# Odoo 10 - Qweb iterate over all sale order lines and calculate total weight

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I would like to iterate over all sale order lines and multiply `product_uom_qty` by `product_id.weight` for each product, then sum up all values to get the total weight of the sale order.

I have seen a construct like this in sale order template:

```
<t t-set="display_discount" t-value="any([l.discount for l in doc.order_line])"/>
```

Which would be the equivalent to perform such aggregated multiplication over all lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar:

```xml
<t t-set="total_weight"
    t-value="sum([l.product_uom_qty * l.product_id.weight for l in doc.order_line])" />
```

Now you can "print out" the variable `total_weight`.